# flink broadcast stream and broadcast state

Tags: apache-flink

As of the broadcast stream and broad caset state, I have two questions.

1. KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction#Context has the following method(getBroadcastState)， I would ask why it is using map state descriptor for the broad cast state? I have thought that broad cast state should use something like BroadcastStateDescriptor and  map state descriptor is used for MapState?

> public abstract <K, V> BroadcastState<K, V> getBroadcastState(final
> MapStateDescriptor<K, V> stateDescriptor);

2. DataStream#broadcast method is defined as follows:

> ```
>   def broadcast(broadcastStateDescriptors: MapStateDescriptor[_, _]*): BroadcastStream[T] = {
>     if (broadcastStateDescriptors == null) {
>       throw new NullPointerException("State Descriptors must not be null.")
>     }
>     javaStream.broadcast(broadcastStateDescriptors: _*)
>   }
> ```

I would ask what the arguments `broadcastStateDescriptors` used for? Why should I have to provide it so early when broadcasting the stream? I think I can create the descriptor and get the broadcast state when I need it in KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction#processBroadcastElement where the operator receives the broadcasted element and update the broadcast state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `MapState` is the kind of state (and the only kind of state) that Flink supports for broadcasting. And since broadcast state is always `MapState`, a `MapStateDescriptor` is what is used to work with it.
2. Flink needs to know how to serialize the data that is being broadcast; `broadcastStateDescriptors` is used by `DataStream#broadcast` for this purpose.